# Why the line breaks are different of CSV (Macintosh) and CSV parsing with using node module csv-parser?

Tags: node.js, typescript, csv, node-streams, node-csv-parse

I'm using node module csv-parser for the streaming csv parsing. It's working fine when uploading a CSV (Comma separated value) but when we upload a CSV (Macintosh) file the problem occurs with line breaks. The CSV that's generated on Windows contains the line breaks like this \r\n but with CSV (MAC) it contains only \r as it's the Mac format. What configuration needs to be done to make it work for both file types?

Here's the code snippet where the streams hooking is done.

```
    // Create a read stream for the passed file path and abort if the file is not found
    let readStream: fs.ReadStream;
    try {
      readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Skipped order batch file processing. File not found.');
      resolve();
      return;
    }

    // Create the CSV transform
    let csvStream: Transform;
    if (file.mapping) {
      csvStream = csv({ headers: false });
    } else {
      csvStream = csv();
    }

    readStream
    .pipe(csvStream);
```

CSV-PARSER has an option of newline parameter it's default value is "\n" using "\r" it worked.

```
 csvStream = csv({ headers: false, newline:"\r" });
```

How can I make the newline value to conditionally set for example if it's csv (Mac) it should "\r" for CSV (Windows) "\r\n" and for linux "\n"?

**Note**: I need to detect this on File Reading.

Your Help would be really appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Please include code as text, not as an image of text.

Comment: Also, please read [the documentation for the software you're using](https://github.com/mafintosh/csv-parser#newline).

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey doing csvStream = csv({ headers: false, newline:"\r" }); worked, but on what basis I can decide the newline to be "\r" or "\n" ?

Comment: If you're only worried about Windows and Mac, you should be able to use "\r" in both cases, since Windows' "\r\n" contains "\r". It's only if you want to also support Unix/Linux's "\n" that you have to get crazy. You'd basically have to read a healthy portion of the file and find out how often "\r" and "\n" show up, if at all. If no "\n", use "\r". If no "\r", use "\n". If both show up with the same frequency, use both.

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey yes as there is no built in quick method available to detect that only the possible solution seems is reading a file chunk and decide the newline on the basis of logic you have suggested. Thanks much!

Comment: @HereticMonkey If I'm reading the file with provided encoding type utf8 it's not printing the new line characters \r, \r\n it's skipping them and if I am reading it with out it's printing the bytes. How to do that part?